# How do I change the 'months' language displayed on the date axis in Chart JS?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, settings

I am using Chart JS to plot data and on the date axis (x-axis) shows '20 Dec 2018', how can I translate the months string to a different language? I was hoping it would be set to whatever language is set on the browser, but nope.

The tooltip, when hovering a data point, needs translation too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I manage to solve this by creating callback functions on `xAxis : ticks` and `tooltips : title` when creating the chart.

Here is my code that sets up the chart.js:

```
<script>

var data = JSON.parse('<?php echo $data?>');

var ctx = document.getElementById("points-given-chart").getContext('2d');

var chartPoints = new Chart( ctx, { 

    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [
            {
                data: data,
                borderWidth: 3,
                label: 'Pontos',
                borderColor: 'rgba(246, 185, 59,1.0)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(250, 211, 144,1.0)',
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        title:      {
            display: false,
            text:    "Pontos"
        },
        scales:     {
            xAxes: [{
                type: "time",
                time: {
                    unit: 'day',
                    tooltipFormat: 'D MMM, YYYY',
                    displayFormats: {
                        day: 'D MMM'
                    },
                    distribution: 'series'
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display:     true,
                },
                ticks : {

                    // Here's where the magic happens:
                    callback: function( label, index, labels ) {

                        return translate_this_label( label );
                    }
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                scaleLabel: {
                    display:     false,
                    labelString: 'Pontos'
                },
                ticks : {
                    beginAtZero : true,
                    callback: function( label, index, labels ) {
                        if ( label > 1 )
                            return formatNumber( label, 0, ',', '.');
                        else
                            return label;
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        elements: {
            line: {
                tension: 0.2, // disables bezier curves
            }
        },
        legend: {
            display: false
        },

        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {

                // Here's where the magic happens:
                title: function( data ) {

                    return translate_this_label( data[0].xLabel );
                },
                label: function ( item, data ) {

                        return 'Pontos: ' + formatNumber( item.yLabel, 0, ',', '.');
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

And here are the helper functions to perform the translations:

```
function translate_month( month ) {

    var result = month;

    switch(month) {

        case 'Feb':
            result = 'Fev' ;
            break;
        case 'Apr':
            result = 'Abr' ;
            break;
        case 'May':
            result = 'Mai' ;
            break;
        case 'Aug':
            result = 'Ago' ;
            break;
        case 'Sep':
            result = 'Set' ;
            break;
        case 'Dec':
            result = 'Dez' ;
            break;

    }

    return result;
}


function translate_this_label( label ) {

    month = label.match(/Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Nov|Dec/g);

    if ( ! month ) 
        return label;

    translation = translate_month( month[0] );
    return label.replace( month, translation, 'g' );
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Import [`moment-with-locales.min.js`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js)

Set your language before chart load:

```
moment.locale('pt-BR');
```

Comment: Just to clarify, ```moment.js``` is required by ```chart.js``` to place time labels. And the same developers also publish ```moment-with-locales.js``` that is made to apply another language. So this is the most straightforward answer and should be the approved solution.

Answer (score 2):

When using Chart.js v2.8+ and moment v2+ you can use [`chartjs-adapter-moment`](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-moment) to automatically translate the axis labels:

```
import moment from "moment";
import "moment/locale/nl";
import Chart from "chart.js";
import "chartjs-adapter-moment";

moment.locale("nl");

new Chart(...);
```